# JSON coming out backwards NSJSONSerializaton

Tags: ios, json

I'm creating a JSON String that's supposed to look like:

```
{ "request_type":"send_string", "security_level":0, "device_type":"ios", "blob":{"string":"blah"}"}
```

This is what I did:

```
NSDictionary *requestData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"send_string",@"request_type",
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"security_level",
                             @"ios",@"device_type",
                             //No Email Provided, This is just for testing
                             blobData,@"blob",
                             nil];
NSData *JSONRequestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

When I print this out with NSLog, I get

```
{"security_level":"0","request_type":"send_string","device_type":"ios","blob":{"string":"hello"}}
```

It comes out of order...what gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered by their nature.  You cannot expect this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are ordered with respect their keys(alphabetical order) by default.